# PHP / MySQL if number of rows is bigger than 6400 doesn't return any results

Tags: php, mysql

I am using simple PHP query to fetch rows from the database, there are above 7000 rows in the table and whenever I fetch all rows, the PHP doesn't work and script dies, but when I limit the results to 6400 everything works fine.
Is there any limitation in MySQL or PHP that I should be aware of? If any, where I need to configure these settings.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Please note that my PHP settings allow the script execution time of 1800 seconds and memory usage is set to 512MB.

Comment: *How* does it die? Any error messages? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: How long does the script run before dying? did you try to run the script on the command like like `php -f /path/the_script.php` and see if you can detect something? can you print the number of rows being returned before you process / display them just to see if the problem is the database or php/webserver?

Comment: When I use the query: "SELECT * FROM table" it just shows empty blank page, but when I use "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 6400" it prints the rows as it should, I am working with error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors', 1), there are no errors shown at all, just dies with blank page. It used to work when there was less than 6490 rows in the table but not anymore. I am afraid this could be some server setting that I am not aware of.

Comment: Try this query to check if it works `select * from tableName limit 6490,610` .

Comment: Everything works as long as I am taking less than 6490 rows from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need that much rows? I'm pretty sure php dies because it runs out of memory.

Run your query in a console to see if you get there more than 7000 rows without issues. If it returns them all there you can be sure it's php and not your database and I'm sure it is php.

For whatever you do, it would be better to loop over the data, also known as "pagination" and read it in chunks of for example 100 rows and process it, 0-100, 100-200, 200-300...

Comment: That was it, the internal memory was set to 32M, I set it up to 256M and it works now. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions as I see it:

1) The one that **@burzum** suggested. Really nice although you would have to empirically establish the max size based on you server load (if it's not constant).

2) Use [mysql_unbuffered_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php)

`mysql_unbuffered_query` does have some drawbacks as described there:

> The benefits of `mysql_unbuffered_query()` come at a cost: you cannot use `mysql_num_rows()` and `mysql_data_seek()` on a result set returned from `mysql_unbuffered_query()`, until all rows are fetched. You also have to fetch all result rows from an unbuffered SQL query before you can send a new SQL query to MySQL, using the same link_identifier.

But since you're dealing with large dataset it seems well justified...